# "What a shame!" versus "Such a shame!"

Tags: differences, idioms, meaning-in-context

I would like to know the difference between "**What a shame!**" and "**Such a shame!"**". When do I use one or the other?

I am Brazilian, so I don't know exactly how to use them.

Comment: Rewrite this question. Give it a shorter title and a longer body. Describe which [dictionaries](http://onelook.com) you've looked these phrases up in, what results you've received, and why you're still confused. Then post your new question on our sister-site, [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com). You should then get a good answer.

Comment: *What a shame* is an exclamation.  *such a shame* is a noun phrase.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, in common usage, there is very little difference between these two.  Both are phrases that are used as a way of conveying a sense of sympathy for the person telling the story (usually by an older woman who is clucking her tongue while saying it).

To my native ear, however, I've always preferred "What a shame!"  "Such a shame!" sounds more like a sentence fragment to my ear.  But, both are commonly used interchangeably.